# Passing Arguments To Class Method Using EE Template

Tags: templates, add-on, custom-classes

**[EDIT: I was able to answer my question. Answer posted below.]**

EE 5.2.4

I have a class that will query an API using item ID and return data for that item.

I am aware that this structure:

```
{exp:my_class:my_method}
```

will return the value for this:

```
class My_class {

  function my_method () {

    // content

  }
}
```

However, what I need to do is pass an argument to the class method for each entry within a channel, like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='products'}
    {exp:my_class:my_method arguments='{product_asin}'}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

would return a value from the class method for each product entry:

```
class My_class {

  function my_method ($asin) {

    // query api based on $asin values passed from the template

  }
}
```

It's quite possible I'm missing something in this part in the docs, as they are quite elaborate regarding add-on classes and methods, so I'm hoping someone will just know from experience how to do something like `{exp:my_class:my_method arguments='{product_asin}'}`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to this.

In the template:

```
{exp:my_class:my_method asin='{product_asin}'}
```

In the class:

```
class My_class {

  function my_method () {

    $asin = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('asin');
    return 'my asin is: ' . $asin;

  }

}
```

On the frontend this renders:

```
my asin is: [product asin]
```

So what you have to do is define your parameter in the template `asin='{product_asin}'` and then fetch it in your method `$asin = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('asin');`.

Thanks, ***me***. Oh, you're welcome!

Comment: Despite your sarcasm, I always recommend scouring the documentation, as it is in there (https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/legacy/libraries/template.html#parameters), but I will give you an upvote on your diligence to solve your own problem!